# SPARQL Request for annotations

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, jena, owl

I try to find a SPARQL query to request annotations. Not an annotation to a class or an individual , I want to request an annotation to the ontology itself (in Protege Active Ontology->Annotation). Additionally, I want to filter the result for only a specific Annotation Property (the type of the annotation).

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you already know the ontology IRI?

Comment: It's hard to help if you don't provide more information.  If you have a particular property, and know the ontology IRI, then it's just `<ontologyIRI> <property> ?value`.  If you don't have the ontology IRI, or it hasn't got one, then you probably just need `[] a owl:Ontology ; <property> ?value`.

Comment: But exactly this does not work. `SELECT *
WHERE {: ?x ?y}` has 0 results. Or is this only a problem with querying in Protege?

Comment: Ok. All that means is that the `:` prefix isn't the same as your ontology IRI. That is actually pretty common, because the ontology IRI probably doesn't have a final `#`, but the prefix probably does.

Comment: `SELECT *
WHERE {<http://www.semanticweb.org/...simpletest> ?x ?y}` has also 0 results.

Comment: Maybe someone can give me a step by step example in Protege from creating a new ontology with a annotation and requesting it. I did already some requests and can't imagine where this type of annotation could be.

Comment: It will be very easy to show you where the information is, if you show us some of your data.

Comment: Ok, what data do you need? What I tried now: Created a new ontology Protege, added one annotation (type: comment) to the ontology itself, did SPARQL-Request `SELECT *
WHERE {?x ?y ?z}` no result, added a class to the ontology, added a annotation to the class, dir SPARQL-Request `SELECT *
WHERE {?x ?y ?z}` the annotation to the class is in the results. So I think now it is not possible to get this type of annotations. The question is: Is this just a problem of Protege-SPARQL-Request-Processor or a general problem of SPARQL?

Comment: Another possibility for me would be to request this type of annotation with apache jena - is there a easy way to request this type of annotation?

Comment: It's probably easier and more straightforward to simply use a SPARQL query, and a SPARQL query is what the question as phrased now asks for.  Until you provide some data though, you're not giving enough to work with:  "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Ok, the 2nd answer is absolutely correct. My problem was that you can't find this type of annotations in Protege (for whatever reason). With Jena QueryExecution everything worked perfectly.

Comment: There's actually probably a reasonable explanation for that:  Protégé doesn't run the query against your ontology file directly (indeed, that would be impossible in the case where you were using a format that's not RDF-based, e.g., the Manchester syntax, or the OWL functional syntax), and there are lots of serialization artefacts in the RDF format that you would not want to see in SPARQL query results (e.g., encoding of axioms).  Still, it's surprising that the annotation properties aren't available, since annotation axioms are part of OWL.

Comment: You should put together an answer based on your experience and mark it as accepted.  Otherwise there's just another unanswered question floating around.

Comment: For what it's worth, I brought this up on the Protégé mailing list, and Matthew Horridge opened up [an issue](https://github.com/protegeproject/org.protege.editor.owl.rdf/issues/1) for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<ontologyIRI> <property> ?value` @Joshua is absolutely correct. My problem was that you can't find this type of annotations in Protege (for whatever reason). With Jena QueryExecution everything worked perfectly.